# Tensor product, Cartesian product and duals

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, factoring

I need some clarification on the idea behind tensor product. I've read a lot about this topic in different sources, but still have big mess in my head.

Let's start from the multilinear maps - a definition of tensors which I believe I do understand. For a given vector space $V$, with base $\{e_\mu\}$ and  $\dim V=n$, all possible linear maps $\varphi_v(v):V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, a so called covectors, form themself a vector space $V^*$, called dual with basis $\{e^\mu\}$. Similarly space $W$ ($\dim W=m$, base $\{f_\nu\}$) has its $W^*$ spanned by $\varphi_w$ with basis $\{f^\nu\}$.

Now, we can create a Cartesian product $V\times W$, with dual $(V\times W)^*$ formed by bilinear maps $\varrho(v,w): V\times W\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and the problem arises: what is the relation between its covectors and individual covectors of $V$ and $W$. To address this issue we create yet another vector space, the tensor product space, which consists of all linear combinations of initial covectors of the form $T_{\mu\nu} e^\mu\otimes f^\nu$. The $\dim V^*\otimes W^*=nm$ is obvious because it is "everybody with everybody". So far, so good. Now, if I understand correctly, they claim that if we act with vector from tensor product space on vector from Cartesian product space, the bilinearity operator factorize, i.e.
$$[T_{\mu\nu} e^\mu\otimes f^\nu](\alpha^\gamma e_\gamma,\beta^\lambda f_\lambda)=T_{\mu\nu}\alpha^\gamma\beta^\lambda e^\mu(e_\gamma)f^\nu(f_\lambda).$$
I cannot understand where did it come from, but some authors just start from this like its obvious. I've used a word factorization, because for me it looks that in this picture $\varrho(v,w)=\varphi_v(v)\varphi_w(w)$. Perhaps I completely misunderstood the idea, can anyone shed some light on this, please?

Comment: use that $e^i(e_j)=\delta^i{}_j$ to simplify

Comment: @janmarqz I know how it works next, that's not the point.

Comment: So you know the scalar functions pull out by linearity, and the part you are struggling with is the
$[e^{\mu}\otimes f^{\nu}](e_{\gamma},f_{\lambda}) = e^{\mu}(e_{\gamma})f^{\nu}(f_{\lambda})$
right?.
Well, people start with this because that is how the tensor product is defined to behave.
In a more abstract setting, it has to do with the universal property definition in category theory.
You can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property) if you are interested.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz yes, the formula you wrote is exactly what I was asking, and yes - I'm reading these days about universal mapping property and other related stuff, so if nobody will give full answer soon I hope I will be able to answer myself.

Comment: Great. Also, on the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870502/why-is-tensor-product-of-linear-maps-defined-as-s-otimes-tv-otimes-w-sv-o?rq=1), it is emphasized the difference between the two concepts of tensor product: tensor product of spaces, and tensor product of maps. The one in your question is of course the tensor product of maps.

I will read a bit more on the subject, and then on these days I may write an answer to this question.